# python construct struct invalid DWORDLONG vallues

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes, construct

I am trying to parse a c struct in python using the construct library
Here is my struct:

```c
typedef struct _MACHINEID {
    UINT32        ui32Hash;
    DWORD        dwLength;
    DWORD        dwMemoryLoad;
    DWORDLONG    ullTotalPhys;
    DWORDLONG    ullAvailPhys;
    DWORDLONG    ullTotalPageFile;
    DWORDLONG    ullAvailPageFile;
    DWORDLONG    ullTotalVirtual;
    DWORDLONG    ullAvailVirtual;
    DWORDLONG    ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
} MACHINEID, * PMACHINEID;
```

```py
from construct import Int32un, Int8sn, Int16un, Int64un, Int
from construct import Array, Struct
MACHINE_ID = Struct(
    'ui32Hash' / Int32un,
    'dwLength' / Int32un,
    'dwMemoryLoad' / Int32un,
    'ullTotalPhys' / Int64un,
    'ullAvailPhys' / Int64un,
    'ullTotalPageFile' / Int64un,
    'ullAvailPageFile' / Int64un,
    'ullTotalVirtual' / Int64un,
    'ullAvailVirtual' / Int64un,
    'ullAvailExtendedVirtual' / Int64un
)
```

But when i receive the struct in python as a bytes object The vallues of all `DWORDLONG` members are incorrect.  Does anyone know whats causing this?

Comment: Padding issue? It's possible that there's padding between the `dwMemoryLoad` and `ullTotalPhys` members. Does the Construct module handle such padding?

Comment: You are right. Putting a `__pragma(pack(push, 1))` and `__pragma(pack(pop))` around my struct which disables padding solves the issue. Thank you :)

Comment: If you can't change the C source, then adding `Padding(4)` after `dwMemoryLoad` will add the proper padding to make  `ullTtotalPhys` start on an 8-byte boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "Some programmer dude" suggested it had to do with padding. Putting `__pragma(pack(push, 1))` and `__pragma(pack(pop))` around my struct to disable padding solves the issue.